# 「fetch」と「await fetch」について

Tags: javascript, promise

**(何れも期待した結果を取得できたのですが、)下記コードは何が違うのですか？**
・それぞれ長所短所があれば知りたいです

---

fetch

```
var response = fetch('/test').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(responseJson) {
});
```

---

await fetch

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/test');
  await response.json();
})();
```

---

・fetch自体は非同期ではない？
・XMLHttpRequesの代わりということであれば、非同期？
・それとも非同期で使用するPromiseを同期的に取得しているだけ？？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async/await はPromiseの糖衣構文なので、より簡単な書き方という理解で良いと思います。JavaScriptのCallback地獄からPromiseが生まれ、そこからまたPromise地獄が生まれたので`async/await`が生まれた、という経緯です。

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: 機能としては同じなのですね。もしかしたら特別な何かがあるのかと思い質問しました

Answer (score 1):

「それぞれ長所短所があれば知りたいです」についてです。

### Generators

`Async/Await`は`Generators`と`Promises`を組み合わせたような「文」です。このような表現ができます。

```
for await (variable of iterable) {
}
```

### 手続き的な表現

`Async/Await`は文なので関数内で処理を遅らせるような表現ができます。

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/test');
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json)
})();
```

### エラー処理

Promiseは`catch`メソッドを用いてエラーを処理できます。

```
fetch('/test').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(responseJson) {
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Async/Awaitは`try-catch`文を用いてエラーを処理します。

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/test');
    await response.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})();
```

Comment: 書式も結構異なるのですね。頭の中がちょっと混乱しかけていたので、参考になりました